# How to assign an item in a list to a random function

Tags: python, python-3.x

For my practice Controlled Assessment in Computer Science, I have to do a "Safety Quiz" in which all the questions have to be given randomly each time the quiz is started. The questions and their respective answers are below:

> 1. What is CEOP?
>      Child Exploitation and Online Protection
>      Criminal Exploration and Online Protection
>      Child Exploitation and Organised Protectors
> 2. When you get an email from someone you do not know, what should you do?
>      Delete it and mark as spam
>      Reply and say hello
>      Forward to your friends
> 3. How secret should you keep your passwords?
>      Never give out passwords except to your parents
>      Give them only to your best friends
>      Give them to strangers
> 4. When an online contact who frightens you asks to meet you in person what should you do?
>      Report to CEOP
>      Arrange to meet them
>      Arrange to meet them with your best friend
> 5. If an email asks you to enter your bank account details because of a problem with your account what should you do?
>      Contact the bank to check if they sent the email
>      Reply to the email
>      Enter your bank account details

My first thought was put all the Questions into a list but then I realized I had no idea how to make each question appear in random order and also how to assign the answers to the questions in the list.

I know how hard this must be to understand but any Hints, Tips and helpful comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should really provide some code snippets that the community can solve. Otherwise there are so many ways to realize your problem. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You should combine questions and answers into one object. You could use a dictionary or a named tuple per question for example, or create custom class to model a question with appropriate answer.

Then put those objects into a list and use [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) to change the order.

Using a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) for example, would look like this:

```
import random
from collections import namedtuple

Question = namedtuple('Question', 'text answers')

questions = [
    Question('What is CEOP?', (
        'Child Exploitation and Online Protection',
        'Criminal Exploration and Online Protection',
        'Child Exploitation and Organised Protectors')),
    Question('When you get an email from someone you do not know, what should you do?', (
        'Delete it and mark as spam',
        'Reply and say hello',
        'Forward to your friends')),
    # ...
]

random.shuffle(questions)
for question in questions:
    print(question.text)
    for answer in question.answers:
        print(answer)
    print()
```

The `Question()` object keeps a question title and the possible answers together. You could add a 3rd field that records which one of the answers is correct, so you can verify the answer picked by whomever takes the quiz.

Comment: Okay that makes sense but could you expand on how to link the questions to the answers in a list. Thanks

Comment: Would it be possible to make each question into a function an include each function inside the list? That way each question and answer would be contained in each function

Comment: @Dop: of course. Functions are just objects. That is not a common way of organising this however. Use classes and put a method on the class to do the work instead.